# We say "After you put the shirt on, you are wearing it". Would you say "After you lay your head on the pillow, you are laying your head on it"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

> [put something](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/put?q=put) + adv./prep. to move something into a particular place
>   or position
>
> Put the cases down there, please.
>
> Did you put sugar in my coffee?
>
> Put your hand up if you need more paper.

---

> [wear](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/wear_1?q=wear) [transitive] wear something to have something on your body
>   as a piece of clothing, a decoration, etc.
>
> He was wearing a new suit.
>
> to wear clothes/clothing
>
> to wear a shirt/hat/uniform
>
> to wear shoes/glasses
>
> Do I have to wear a tie?
>
> Was she wearing a seat belt?
>
> She never wears make-up.
>
> All delegates must wear a badge.
>
> She always wears black (= black clothes).
>
> I've got nothing to wear.
>
> One woman decided to wear flowers in her hair.

---

> [lay](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/lay_1?q=lay) [transitive] to put somebody/something in a particular position,
>   especially when it is done gently or carefully
>
> lay somebody/something + adv./prep. He laid a hand on my arm.
>
> Relatives laid wreaths on the grave.
>
> She laid the baby down gently on the bed.
>
> Red roses were laid at the memorial.
>
> She noticed some paintings laid against the far wall.
>
> The horse laid back its ears.
>
> lay something His mother visited the murder scene yesterday to lay
>   flowers.
>
> lay somebody/something + adj. The cloth should be laid flat.

So, we say "**After you put the shirt on, you are wearing it**" because the state of "**put**" & "**wear**" are different.

My question is that

Do we use a different verb to express "**your head is on the pillow**" after you lay your head on the pillow?

For example, Would you say "**After you lay your head on the pillow, you are laying your head on it**" the same way we say "**After you put the shirt on, you are wearing it**"?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey, when we say "to lie on something" we think the whole body from the top of the head to the feet are on something. If we say "you are lying on the pillow", people may thing the pillow is big enough to cover the whole body.

Comment: There are too many lines of definition in your question. It makes it difficult to read. After you have laid your head on the pillow, your head is lying on the pillow.

Comment: Yeah, there's no point in quoting entire dictionary entries – example sentences in particular. Stop doing that, please.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty, and the meaning "lie" of "laid your head on the pillow" is different from the "lie" of "lying on the pillow". The former means "put" & the latter means "to be or remain in a flat position on a surface", right?

Comment: @Tom Yes, check the dictionary entries for "lay" and "lie". They are two different words. the first is transitive, and the second is intransitive. They have some coincident forms "I lay it down" (present tense of "lay"), and "I lay there for hours." (past tense of "lie"). They are sometimes confused by native speakers.

Comment: In your first title example, ***put*** is a ***present tense*** verb form (to match *you **are** wearing it*). So you should do the same with the second example: *After you **lay** your head on the pillow, you are...*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way of saying it...

"After you have laid your head on the pillow, your head is lying on the pillow."

The key to the puzzle is actually mentioned on the same dictionary page you already quoted.  It says

"Which Word? lay / lie"

[Lie](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/lie1_1) is a different word than [lay](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/lay_1?q=lay). Lying means reclining. Laying means placing.  *Two completely different words.*  So, that's probably the cause of the confusion.